# I have a Polish work permit and a type-D national visa from a company I decided not to join. Can I travel to the Schengen region?

Tags: visa, working-visas, schengen, poland

Some months back I was issued a Polish work permit and I used it get a Type-D national visa. After that, I decided to work for some other company (Not located in Europe) and rejected the Polish company's job offer.

I am planning to visit the Schengen region for tourism. Can I use the same visa for that purpose or do I have to apply for a new one?

Answer (score 1):

No, since you don't have the intention to use the D-Visa for the purpose which it was issued for (working in Poland), you must apply for C-Visa for a visit instead.